# How does one parse argument values from a function with a varying arguments signature?

Tags: javascript, function, parsing, arguments, variadic

I have a function called "Time", it accepts from 0 to 6 arguments.

```
function Time(year,month,day,hour,minutes,options) {

}
```

Parameters month, day, hour and minutes cannot be defined if the previous one isn't defined.

Even if the "options" parameter is optional, if present, it has to be the last parameter.

However, user can define only year and month for example, and then options.

How to avoid the user to have to write this:

```
var newTimeInstance = Time(2024,06, undefined, undefined, undefined, options {
   fr: {
     // ...
   },
   es: {
     // ...
   }
})
```

If it's not possible, is there another way to join options to a function ?

I've tried: `var newTimeInstance = Time(2024,01).options({ ... })` but then I'm unable to access the other constructor functions in newTimeInstance.

Comment: `var newTimeInstance = Time({year:2024, month: 6})` The other benefit is that it's much easier to see what's happening.

Comment: If they must be positional, you're basically stuck with `function Time(maybeYearOrOptions, maybeMonthOrOptions, maybeDayOrOptions, maybeHourOrOptions, maybeMinutesOrOptions, maybeOptions) { /* ... */ }` and then checking _inside the function_ what you actually got. JavaScript does not have named parameters, _only_ positional (but those positional parameters can, as above, be objects).

Comment: Indeed, it kind of adds a lot of text to write because I've found useful to be able to just do Time(2024,06,15) but thanks for this viable solution :)

Comment: Pass parameters as array

Comment: And then check if one of the parameter is an array?

Comment: @Ravneet I don't see how that helps, given that varargs can be used as `...args` or the `arguments` object can be used. Both basically give you an array without requiring the consumer to jump through implementation hoops.

Comment: You're basically stuck with something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDJXjW), which isn't great to work with from either side of the interface!

Comment: @AnnMB …the function of question, can it be changed, can its arguments signature be reimplemented? Or are you more looking for a way to always ensure a parsable parameter precedence and parsable argument values, before passing them on to the `Time` function. In case the implementation can be changed, choose a single object based parameter which holds all the necessary and optional parameters. Obtaining any value then is a piece of cake, thanks to [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)

Comment: @AnnMB ... and in case of having to implement a function with a varying arguments signature, like presented with the example code, one needs a parsing approach which makes assumptions based on argument values. Within such an algorithm one has to decide whether an arguments signature is valid and whether to sanitize some values or throw an error. For the latter case I did provide a late answer with executable example code.

Comment: @AnnMB ... regarding all the later provided answers / solutions are, there any questions left?

Answer (score 2):

Inconvenient, but you could do:

```js
function Time(...args) {
  if (args.length === 3) {
    const [year, month, options] = args
    console.log({
      year,
      month,
      options
    })
  }
  // other cases
}

Time(2024, 4, {
  extra: 'options'
})
```

Comment: Could cover some cases but unfortunately, the "options" parameter is always optional.

Comment: That way you have a lot of `args.length` checks, too. I think the fastest way to get useful values is `const options = args.at(-1);`, then either: it's an object and you destructure the rest positionally from `args.slice(-1)`; or it's not and you destructure the rest positionally from `args`.

Comment: Tried that. It works, but it's very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

How about a custom arguments parsing approach, covered by a utility/helper function, where one in addition, at a more detailed scale, would decide whether an arguments signature is valid and whether to sanitize some values or throw an error ...

```js
function isObjectObject(value) {
  return (/^\[object\s+Object\]$/).test(
    Object.prototype.toString.call(value)
  );
}

function parseArgumentsSignature(args) {
  const params = [];
  let options;
  let error;

  args
    .slice(0, 6)

    // every allows an early exit while using a callback function.
    .every((value, idx) => {
      let proceed = true;

      if (isObjectObject(value)) {

        options = value;
        proceed = false;

      } else if (value == null) {

        params[idx] = undefined;
      } else {
        value = parseInt(value, 10);
        if (Number.isFinite(value)) {

          params[idx] = value;
        } else {
          error = new TypeError('Invalid arguments signature.');

          proceed = false;
        }
      }
      return proceed;
    });

  return (error && {
    error,
  } || {
    params, 
    ...(options && { options } || {}),
  });
}

function Time(...args/* year, month, day, hour, minutes, options */) {
  const parsed = parseArgumentsSignature(args);

  if (Object.hasOwn(parsed, 'error')) {
    throw parsed.error;
  }
  const {
    params: [
      year = 0, month = 0, day = 0, hour = 0, minutes = 0,
    ],
    options = null,
  } =
    parsed;

  console.log({
    year, month, day, hour, minutes, options, params: parsed.params,
  });
}

console.log(
  "Time(...[2024, 06,,, null, null, { fr: 'fr', es: 'es' }]);"
);
Time(...[2024, 06,,, null, null, { fr: 'fr', es: 'es' }]);

console.log(
  "Time(...[2024, 06,,,, { fr: 'fr', es: 'es' }]);"
);
Time(...[2024, 06,,,, { fr: 'fr', es: 'es' }]);

console.log(
  "Time(2024, { fr: 'fr', es: 'es' });"
);
Time(2024, { fr: 'fr', es: 'es' });

console.log(
  "Time(2024, 06);"
);
Time(2024, 06);

console.log(
  "Time(2024, 'foo bar');"
);
Time(2024, 'foo bar');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The easiest way of cause is a change of the function's variadic arguments signature towards a **single object-based configuration-like parameter**.

```js
function Time({
  year = 0, month = 0, day = 0, hour = 0, minutes = 0, options = {},
}) {
  console.log({
    year, month, day, hour, minutes, options
  });
}

console.log(
  "Time({ year: 2024, month: 6, options: { fr: 'fr', es: 'es' } });"
);
Time({ year: 2024, month: 6, options: { fr: 'fr', es: 'es' } });

console.log(
  "Time({ year: 2024, options: { fr: 'fr', es: 'es' } });"
);
Time({ year: 2024, options: { fr: 'fr', es: 'es' } });

console.log(
  "Time({ year: 2024, month: 6 });"
);
Time({ year: 2024, month: 6 });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Object for arguments with a default empty value (`{param1, param2, ..., paramx} = {}`, aka [destructuring assigment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)).

That way you'll always have named variables. It's a bit more typing calling the function, but it offers better (named) parameter handling,
flexibility (e.g. you can add parameters without breaking/necessarily having to refactor existing calls to the function), the user just has to supply the arguments needed and doesn't need to provide them in a fixed order.

Looks like:

```js
function Time({year,month,day,hour,minutes,options = `dst:0`} = {}) {
  console.log(`your input: ${year ? `year: ${year}` : ``}${
    month ? `, month: ${month}` : ``}${
    day ? `, day: ${day}` : ``}${
    hour ? `, hour: ${hour}` : ``}${
    minutes ? `, minutes: ${minutes}` : ``} (options: ${options})`);
}

Time();
Time({year: 2024, hour: 12, options: `dst:1`});
Time(`this is not available`);
Time({year: 2024, month: 0, day: 21, hour: 12, minutes: 30,});

const now = new Date();
const params = {
  year: now.getFullYear(),
  month: now.getMonth(),
  day: now.getDate(),
  hour: now.getHours(),
  minutes: now.getMinutes(),
  options: `dst:1`
};
Time(params);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Array::reduceRight()` to check `arguments`:

```js
function Time(year,month,day,hour,minutes,options) {
  [...arguments].reduceRight((r, arg, idx, arr) => {
    if(arg === undefined && arr[idx + 1] !== undefined) throw new Error('An argument cannot be undefined');
  });
}

Time(2024, 3, undefined); // ok
Time(undefined, 2); // an error
```